# Can't set manual IP to Virtualbox Host Only adapter in CentOS 6.5

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-8.1

When I configure the IP address of VirtualBox 4.3.2 (running on Windows 8.1) host only adapter, it changes it back to some other IP. Guest OS is CentOS 6.5.

I tried to set the IP in network connections in device manager. But I get this error after I clicked on properties of TCP/IPv4:

> In order to configure tcp/ip you must install newtwork adapter.

I want to give these settings to Host only adapter:

- **IP:** 10.20.0.2
- **Mask:** 255.255.255.0

DHCP disabled.

But it automatically gets changed to something like:

- **IP:** 169.254.134.67 // Not fixed every time a new one
- **Mask:** 255.255.0.0

Here is the output of `hostonlyifs`:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage list hostonlyifs

Name:            VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
GUID:            ce2a5907-6034-4bb0-a45d-e30e90c17483
DHCP:            Enabled
IPAddress:       169.254.134.67
NetworkMask:     255.255.0.0
IPV6Address:     fe80:0000:0000:0000:08bf:284e:1182:8643
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64
HardwareAddress: 08:00:27:00:28:da
MediumType:      Ethernet
Status:          Up
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
```

As you can see above it shows DHCP enbled even though I did not enable it.

I tried doing this:

```
VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" --ip 10.20.0.2 --netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Still nothing happens.

I have disabled APIPA now the IP gets changed to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Guest is CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 13):

Not 100% sure what your setup is, but will explain that typically a “host-only” adapter in VirtualBox is a second network interface in addition to your main network interface.

For example, on my Mac OS X setup of VirtualBox, under “Preferences…” for VirtualBox itself —under “Network” tab/panel—I have a “host-only” adapter that is called `vboxnet0`. That is set as follows in the “Adapter” panel:

[image]

Note that I have the following set in the “Adapter” panel:

- **IPv4 Address:** `192.168.56.1`
- **IPv4 Network Mask:** `255.255.255.0`
- **IPv6 Address:** `[blank]`
- **IPv6 Network Mask:** `0`

I also have the “DHCP Server” set to disabled. Note also that for this example, the network range for this adapter would be `192.168.56.x`. If you want this adapter to be a part of the `10.20.0.x` range, then change the IPv4 address of the adapter from `192.168.56.1` to `10.20.0.1`.

Then, in the actual “Settings” for the virtual machine you want to have this setup for, click “Settings”. Now, the main adapter—“Adapter 1”—should be set to the standard defaults as pictured here:

[image]

But then under “Adapter 2” you want to enable that adapter and set the “Attached to:” as “Host-only Adapter” and then set the “Name:” `vboxnet0` as pictured here:

[image]

With that done, start up your guest OS—I am using Ubuntu, but this should work for most any Linux guest OS such as CentOS—and then type in the following to manually start up your new network connection on the second network port:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.56.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Note I have chosen the `192.168.56.10` address for the static address of this interface. You can set that to anything within the range of `192.168.56.2` to `192.168.56.255`. I simply chose the `.10` address since it’s simple to remember; at least for me. And if you wanted to set the address to `10.20.0.2`—assuming your address is in the `10.20.0.x` range—then just change `192.168.56.10` to `10.20.0.2`.

Now that `sudo ifconfig` only inits a temporary connection. If you were to reboot right now, that connection would be lost. So if you want to set this up as a permanent setting you would have to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows. First, open up that file using your favorite text editor; I like to use [`nano`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nano):

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

The contents of that file would look something like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Note how the setting for `eth0` is DHCP; leave that as is. To add the new network interface, you would add something like this to the bottom of the file:

```
# The local hostmachine access interface.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Note how `eth1` is set to `static` and has `address` and `netmask` settings.  Once added, just save the file. And now on reboot you machine will always know to assign `eth1` and if you want to reach that guest OS from the host OS, you would just need to go to `192.168.56.10`. And if you wanted to set the address to `10.20.0.2`—assuming your address is in the `10.20.0.x` range—then just change `192.168.56.10` to `10.20.0.2`.

Comment: i am trying to install Mirantis Fuel Openstack 6.0 On VirtualBox. For that i need 3 host only adapters with static IPs : 10.20.0.2 , 172.16.0.1, 172.16.1.1 with mask 255.255.255.0. If possible can you please look into http://docs.mirantis.com/openstack/fuel/fuel-6.0/virtualbox.html and suggest me what should i do?

Comment: Since the virtual box is giving APIPA to host only network by itself, would it work if i gave that APIPA as address in the eth1 ?

Comment: The problem is, whatever IP i set in the Network>Preferences>Host only adapter, The VirtualBox automatically changes it to something like 169.254.*.*

Comment: Check these 3 screenshots :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-H3U6bbNi4YNEJwQ3hqalBQMGc/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-H3U6bbNi4YS3JEcmRTeS01aTA/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-H3U6bbNi4YeEFNZDFrUzYyYUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Note: on newer versions of Ubuntu (16.04, for instance) substitute eth1 to enp0s8 and you should be good to go.