# How to reliably set up communication between the VirtualBox guest OS and host OS?

Tags: networking, windows-8, virtualbox, nat

I have a VirtualBox (Windows 8 guest on a Windows 8 host) with NAT networking set up. I would like to set up the guest system to emit Growl messages that would be picked up by a service on the host.

Here’s my problem: I’m on a laptop and frequently connects to a variety of networks. The IP address of my host machine is constantly changing. So how to configure Growl on the guest so that it can reliably send messages to my host?

My impression is that I should be able to do something with Windows networking, or set up an additional networking adapter with a private network that has static IPs. Short of this hand-waving though I don’t know how to proceed.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a Virtualbox (Windows 8 guest on a Windows 8 host) with NAT
>   networking set up. I would like to set up the guest system to emit
>   Growl messages that would be picked up by a service on the host.

Pretty easy if you setup an additional “host-only adapter” on the guest OS. I go into detail on [how to do that in Mac OS X in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/873309/167207), but the same overall concepts should work fine for Windows. Just keep your current “Adapter 1” setup 100% the same, but then enable “Adapter 2” as the “host-only adapter” and configure it as per the instructions.

Once you have that “host-only adapter” setup, you can then setup Growl on the guest OS to send data to the host OS on the IP address of `192.168.56.1` which will—of course—never ever change since that is just a VirtualBox router host gateway address.

Comment: This sounds like what I need. Thanks Jake. So what I don't get though is how does the guest know to set only traffic to `192.168.56.1` to `Adapter 2` and the rest to `Adapter 1`?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just thought there was something additional that I would have to do