# VirtualBox VM with Kali Linux cannot be reached from the host OS

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

I have a VirtualBox VM with Kali Linux installed on it and every thing works fine, but I have one problem.

When I setup a netcat listener on it, and I try to connect to it from my main OS, nothing happens.

I am not able to acces my Apache2 server outside of the VM. When I ping the Kali Linux VM’s IP address I get this:

```
Pinging [Kali Ip] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for [Kali Ip]:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't set manual IP to Virtualbox Host Only adapter in CentOS 6.5](https://superuser.com/questions/873189/cant-set-manual-ip-to-virtualbox-host-only-adapter-in-centos-6-5)

Comment: Unfortunately not.